# Is putting views as UITableViewCell inside tableView is a good approach?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tree xib file, called LogoStyle1(cyan colored square), FieldStyle1(purple color square), ButtonStyle1(yellow colored square).
I created UITableView (black colored square). Inside TableView, I put all xibs.

My question is to do this a good approach or Do I need to do all separate customView for xibs without TableView. Because using dequeReusableCell with no need reusable cell.

Note: Actually I bought a app template and try to understand why author does this.

[image]

xib custom classes:

```
class LogoStyle1: UITableViewCell {
}

class FieldStyle1: UITableViewCell {
}


class ButtonStyle1: UITableViewCell {
}
```

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createView()     }
```

function createView

```
func createView() {

    // Create Header

    // Create Table
    tableStyle.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    tableStyle.delegate = self;
    tableStyle.dataSource = self;
    tableStyle.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 243/255.0, green: 246/255.0, blue: 249/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    tableStyle.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
    tableStyle.allowsSelection = false
    tableStyle.isScrollEnabled = false

    // register UINib for LogoStyle1, FieldStyle1, ButtonStyle1
    tableStyle.register(UINib(nibName: "LogoStyle1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "LogoStyle1")
    tableStyle.register(UINib(nibName: "FieldStyle1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "FieldStyle1")
    tableStyle.register(UINib(nibName: "ButtonStyle1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ButtonStyle1")

    self.view.addSubview(tableStyle)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 120
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 272
    }else{
        return 94
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LogoStyle1", for: indexPath) as! LogoStyle1
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FieldStyle1", for: indexPath) as! FieldStyle1
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonStyle1", for: indexPath) as! ButtonStyle1
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    default:
        break
    }

    let cell = UITableViewCell() // cell nil
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you aren't adding views directly to the tableview ie you're not doing `tableView.addSubview(xyzView)` then you're good.

TableView is powerful in the sense that it provides you the option to add footers, headers for 'each section' or the 'tableview' entirely itself.

What you might (I'm not sure if you're doing this or not) be doing and is wrong is to add another tableviewCell to create something in place of a footer for your section or tableview itself.

Comment: Normally, when we are doing simple login screen we use just views. logoStyle1 view, fieldStyle1 view, buttonStyle1 view. This author used tableview, views as tableViewCell. Normally we use tableViews for reusable cells. İn this case, there is no need to use reusable cell. Because we have only 3 cell. So ı asked this question. Why did he used tableView as long as there is no need to use reusable cell in this example.

Comment: I know you're trying to understand and it's always good to be have this kind of critical thinking. Along the way you may learn that people better than you will do things either for no reason or simply put they will make a mistake. Sometimes they just don't care of maybe it's that they have more important immediate needs. From what you're saying perhaps stackviews would have been more suitable...

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about adding subviews directly to the table view, not to its cells, then this is a **VERY** bad idea. You should treat a table view's content view as private.

It sounds like what you need is a static table view. I suggest reading up on that. (You'll need to use a `UITableViewController` and a storyboard for that.)

Comment: No adding views to cells. cell1 = "LogoStyle1", cell2 = "FieldStyle1", cell3 = "ButtonStyle1". İn xibs,  LogoStyle1, FieldStyle1,  ButtonStyle1 classes type of TableViewCell.

Comment: Uptaded question content.